# CARBON FIELDS как в комплексном поле задать размер изображения (миниатюры)?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php 

use Carbon_Fields\Container;
use Carbon_Fields\Field;

Container::make('post_meta', 'Вложенные комплексные поля')

  ->add_tab('Просто вкладка',[
      Field::make( 'complex', 'image_box', 'Комплексное поле' )
          ->set_layout( 'tabbed-horizontal' )
          ->add_fields( array( 
            Field::make( 'image', 'image_box_item', 'Изображение' ) 
               ->set_value_type( 'url' )
          ) )
  ]);
```

Код в шаблоне такой:

```
  <?php $image_box = carbon_get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_box');   ?>

    <?php foreach ( $image_box as  $image_box_item ) { ?>

      <div class="image">
        <img src="<?php echo $image_box_item['image_box_img']; ?> " alt="">
      </div>

   <?php  } ?>
```

С простым полем изображения это можно проделать вот так:

```
Field::make("image", "photo", "Фото")

<php $thumbnail_id = carbon_get_post_meta($post_id, 'photo');    ?>

<php thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $thumbnail_id, 'full' ); ?>

<!-- выводим миниатюру рубрики на экран -->
<img src="<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?>" alt="" />
```

Но как это проделать в комплексном поле ??? 
С php я мало знаком, вот и прошу помощи у гуру своего дела.
Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет как решить мою проблему!

Answer (score 0):

Убрать

```
>set_value_type( 'url' )
```

после строки

```
Field::make( 'image', 'image_box_item', 'Изображение' )
```

Тогда можно получить id картинки и воспользоваться

```
$thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_box_item['image_box_img'], 'full' );

<div class="image">
        <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?> " alt="">
</div>
```

И загрузить картинки заново.